# ORA-01555 error at insertion of table

Tags: oracle11g

1. Hello ExPert my oracle DB version is 11g R2. I got one strage error
   ORA-01555 (Snapshot too old error) when ever i am inserting one
   master table to archiving table, by using parallel hints.

   I also tried by using For all bulk collect concept but still same
   error.

   Then i check the DB side and update the undo_retention parameter as
   1800 ,which is advisable for our application but still same issue
   persist. Any help will really appreciate?   What is best way to
   configure the rollback segment area to avoid this error. Please note
   the master table have some LOB Fields. Asked by santosh.

Comment: This appears to be identical to the question that you asked yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108926/insertion-of-table-cause-ora-01555-error-in-oracle-db-version-is-11g-r2  We'd still need more information.  Are you writing the data in a single transaction or are you committing in a loop?  How long does the transaction take?  How did you determine that 1800 is the proper setting for `undo_retention`?  How much UNDO do you generate while the process is running?  How big is your UNDO tablespace?  Is it set to autoextend?

Answer (score 0):

There might be various non-trivial reasons. In case on inserts common explanations for ORA-01555 might not apply.

Possible explanations can be:

- you use dictionary based tablespace and the error was triggered by recursive sql. (but probably this is not the root case, dictionary based tablespaces are not used anymore)
- integrity constraints. Some other process modified parent table (and it's index) and your insert failed to validate
- LOB index corruption, or some other problem with lobs. You use 11g where there were several problems with lobs. Aside from usual UNDO, there are also rollback segments created inside LOB segments. Check database alert log and there should be ORA-1555, if you find that `duration=0`. Which is quite unusual value for ORA-1555 the you have problem with lob undo space - which is something different form UNDO tablespace. And you have to tune LOB storage parameters.

PS: undo_retention parameter is ignored by the database when UNDO datafiles are NOT autoextensible.
PS1: this question should be moved to dba.stackexchange.com